# Multipicative group and Additive groups

Tags: group-theory

Maybe it's a silly question but how exactly do you find a multiplicative group and additive group? Is it always a modulo function?

How do you find the multiplicative group and additive group of real numbers?

An example or maybe a few, would be very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: A multiplicative or additive group is a group under multiplication or addition.  There are many examples, such as  $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Q$, $\mathbb R$, or $\mathbb C$ under addition; the latter 3 without {$0$} under multiplication; groups of permutations under composition; groups of invertible matrices under multiplication; integers modulo $n$ under addition; and integers modulo a prime $p$ without {$0$} under multiplication

Comment: Your question is vague. You already mention two specific groups: additive group of real numbers, its elements are all real numbers with the operation being addition. The other group  consists of all non-zero real numbers and the operation is multiplication. Having specified the groups , what do you mean by "finding them"?

If your question describes a *particular kind* of groups and asks how to find examples of  such a kind then  it would make sense.

Comment: Think of symmetry groups. Here we compose isometries. The composition is not addition and also not multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

We tend to call the group operation multiplication regardless of whether it is multiplication or not.

Addition modulo $n$ will form a group.

Multiplication modulo $n$ is a little trickier.  If we take the integers that are co-prime with $n$ we can form a group with the multiplication as the group operation.

But, our group operation may not be addition or multiplication.  It may be something else entirely, it may be function composition, for example.

i.e. the set of bijective functions from $A\to A$ forms a group, with group operation as composition.

The group may represent geometry.  The set of rigid motions in the plane forms a group.

Answer (score -1):

Any set with a binary operation that satisfies the group axioms is a group.

Comment: set with a binary operation

Comment: @J.W. Tanner see edit